# Mobile phone app that can log and export phone signal quality with GPS location

Tags: android-app

Im after an android app that can log phone signal quality and gps location and that i can later download the results.

The phone signal logging should be able to indicate download rate.

Nperf is an app that can log that dat through active mapping but its not individually reviewable.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and build any sort of flow that you'd like, including everything you wrote, like mobile data usage tracking for download rate.

Some references:

- [variables](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/variables.html), including `%CELLSIG` - call signal strength
- [actions](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html), including **Write File** with which you can append to a log or **Get Location** to get coordinates stored in `%LOC` variable
- [states](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html)/[events](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/eh_index.html) to enable the logging under whatever chosen circumstances (low signal - **Signal Strength** state, button click - e.g.**Button Widget Clicked** or many other possibilities)